# Cropping Shape of Square Image Android In App

Tags: java, android, image, crop

I want to create an application which allows the user to resize an image in shape of square (length = width).

I know that it is possible to use the gallery to make that in this way:

```
private void crop(Uri photoUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setData(photoUri);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CROP);
}
```

**But I would like to know if there is a library which allows to make that directly in the application?**

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html. you can use the code in the link for cropping. This does nto use any library

Comment: Thank @Raghunandan, but this is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found my solution [here](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) but I accept other answers!!

[image: Cropper]

Comment: Is there any alternative ? I want to implement it from scratch...I want to crop image during the capture not after the capture

Answer (score 0):

I used this library https://arthurhub.github.io/Android-Image-Cropper/

See the example code in sample project in addition to that you have to fix the aspect ratio and set the scale to 1.

```
cropImageView.setFixedAspectRatio(true);
cropImageView.setScaleX(1.0f);
cropImageView.setScaleY(1.0f);
```