# Android pick and crop image on OS 2.3

Tags: android, crop, android-gallery

is there any way to achieve pick and crop image from build-in android gallery on 2.3?
I have found this library:
[com.android.camera.action.CROP alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189247/com-android-camera-action-crop-alternative)

But it seems to work only on API lvl 15 and higher.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593156/cropping-shape-of-square-image-android-in-app

Answer (score 0):

I used the following crop library. Its really good and it supports 2.3 and above. Try it.

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage